# Wireless connection not showing as connected in start bar

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I recently re-installed my wireless card driver and since then the mini icon for the wireless is showing the "not connected" symbol and not the "connected" symbol.  Any ideas why?

I had to install the Netgear Wizard when I reinstalled the driver, but it's not running and I've disabled it from starting up with the PC.

[image]

IPConfig

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing in what you're reporting. The obvious answer is that you're not connected to any wireless networks.

Assuming that's not the case, you'll need to provide us more details. Please open up command prompt and show us the output from running "ipconfig -all"

Comment: You can see I'm logged into the the network Clements 4 and have full internet access (in fact I posted the initial question from that PC)?  I'll get the ipconfig data when I'm back at that PC later

Comment: I've updated the question now with that info

Comment: Ah ok. I would take a look under [Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections]

Sometimes there are other "Not connected" wireless or virtual adapter under there that have priority over that icon status. First, if any of your adapters is bridged, I would remove the bridge. Then test one by one whether disabling those "Not connected" devices will allow the icon to show a connected status.

Comment: The 2 other adapters are disabled in my network connections, so it's not that!